# java wait-notify mechanism among different processes

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a very basic question about wait-notify mechanism in Java. I know that we can synchronize two different threads by using this, however, do these threads need to be running in the same process? What if there are two threads running in two different processes? Would wait-notify approach still work?

Comment: All the answers below are correct. I just had to accept one, so I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start the JVM process, every thread you create and the memory you use belong to that JVM instance and none other.

When you launch another JVM instance, these two instances do not share memory resources. Hence wait/notify (or any other object for that matter) will only be accessible for threads belonging to that instance of JVM and not other process.

Answer (score 2):

Wait-notify won't work for threads running in different processes.

Suppose process A allocated memory of `0x1000`-`0x2000`, and is synchronizing on a lock `0x1200`

Process B allocates memory of `0x3000`-`0x4000`. It can't possibly get access to `0x1200`, can it...

Your best synchronization approaches at that point will be

- have the processes talk to each other over local TCP/IP sockets
- have the processes read & write lock file(s)

Comment: +1 FYI:  It's important with Java to resist the temptation to talk about memory addresses since all objects are relocatable.  You should use the word "reference" instead of memory.

Answer (score 1):

No, different processes start different JVM, so threads aren't communicating there. The mechanism works with threads are running on the same JVM.

`wait()` release the object monitor and go to a infinite sleep while some other threads continue to execute. 
`notify()` wakes up the first thread that called `wait()` on the same object monitor.